# Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList[] needs unchecked conversion

Tags: java, multithreading, casting

I am working on a project in which I am getting TypeSafety issues on initializing one method with a particular size. In my run method, I have yellow line on the `new ArrayList[tableLists.size()]` and complaining about-

`Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<Method>[]`

Below is the code.

```
private ArrayList<Method> methods[] = null;


    @Override
    public void run() {

        methods = new ArrayList[tableLists.size()];


    }
```

How can I fix this `TypeSafety` issue here?

**Updated:-**

```
    int j = 0;
    dbConnection = new Connection[tableLists.size()];
    callableStatement = new CallableStatement[tableLists.size()];
    methods = new ArrayList[tableLists.size()];

    //loop around the map values and make the connection list
    for (Map<String, String> map : tableLists.values()) {

        dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(map.get("URL"), map.get("USER"), map.get("PASSWORD"), map.get("DRIVER"));
        callableStatement[j] = dbConnection[j].prepareCall(map.get("SQL"));

        methods[j] = getRequiredMethods(map.get("SUFFIX"));
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: You're creating an array of `ArrayList` objects here. Are you sure that's really what you want?

Comment: @Jake, yeah I needed that. See my updated question with the updated code. Is there anything wrong with that? Or any better approach?

Comment: Not familiar with Java but, don't you need to specify the type in the ArrayList there ? methods = new ArrayList<Method>[tableLists.size()];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the methods themselves don't seem to be separated in any particular way, why not just store them all in the same `ArrayList`, bypassing the problem entirely?

```
ArrayList<Method> methods;

/* ... */

methods.addAll(getRequiredMethods(map.get("SUFFIX")));
```

Arrays and generics tend not to play very nice with each other. If you *really* need the separation, you have to primary options:

1. Use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Method>>` instead of an array. This will let you handle everything nicely without mucking with plain arrays. You can then efficiently initialize the `methods` object with a size just like with a regular array.

   ```
   methods = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Method>>(tableLists.size());
   ```
2. If you *really* need to use an array, you'll probably have to suppress the warning using the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation. This is ugly and annoying, so I'd avoid it if you can.

Comment: Yeah I can do that but for zero index there will be different methods and for 1 index, there will be different methods. So that is the reason I am doing it like this so that I can differentiate what to call basis on the index.

Comment: If I am using your first option, then I cannot do like this `methods[j] ` to store the corresponding methods on a particular index, see my updated code second last line. So suppose if I am going with your first option then how can I make this thing to work? And with your second option that I already know and I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Nevzz03 `List` provides random access for both getting and setting. Instead of `method[j] = x`, you would use `method.add(j, x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way to create an array list,

```
private ArrayList<Method> methods[] = new ArrayList<>();
```