# Unable to retrive the data from database. Getting a runtime error. here's an instance of my servlet DBController.java

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

servlet: DBController.java

```
java.sql.Statement statement = conn.createStatement();


            ResultSet rs2=statement.executeQuery("select * from stud_db");

            while(rs2.next())

            {



int id2= rs2.getInt("id"); 


String name2= rs2.getString("name");

int age2=rs2.getInt("age");

String address2= rs2.getString("address");

float percentage2 = rs2.getFloat("percentage");


request.setAttribute("id",id2);  

request.setAttribute("name",name2);

request.setAttribute("age", age2);  

request.setAttribute("address",address2);

request.setAttribute("percentage", percentage2);


request.getRequestDispatcher("/next.jsp").include(request,response);
```

My jsp page

next.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>next page</title>

</head>

<body>

<center><h1>DATA SUCCESSFULLY ENTERED</h1></center>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<h2>Details are shown below </h2>

<body>


<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/DBController" method="POST">


<table border="2">

<tr>

<td>ID</td>

<td>NAME</td>

<td>AGE</td>

<td>ADDRESS</td>

<td>PERCENTAGE</td>

</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}"> </c:forEach>

 <tr>    

     <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>

     <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>

     <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>

     <td><c:out value="${row.address}"/></td>

    <td><c:out value="${row.percentage}"/></td>  

    </table>


</form>


<h1>Thank you..</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Close of while loop ?

Comment: sir
the problem is no data is being displayed in the table as you can see above
ID NAME AGE are coming blank...
how to resolve this?

Comment: "Getting runtime error"... which error ?

Comment: the data is not displayed ... 
for example if there are 21 entries in my sql database then next.jsp will show this above message 21 times.. 
this is the problem.

Comment: <tr>    
     <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
         
     <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>
   
     <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
     
     <td><c:out value="${row.address}"/></td>
     
    <td><c:out value="${row.percentage}"/></td>  

    </table>

i think this code is not working.. plz help me in this.

Comment: anyone plz??
resolve this trouble

Comment: why are you using `result.rows`.where are you setting attribute `result.rows`?

Comment: i think the attributes are not directing from servlet to jsp..
and it it showing a blank form on browser.
plz tell me how should i direct it to the jsp

Comment: i have included jsdl jar files in webinf and apache and made all the necessary connections

Comment: Better way is to create pojo class with defined fields.Then set object and add it to arraylist.Then set attribute of arrylist and use that in jsp.Also use arraylist attribute name as `items` in jsp

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}"> 

 <tr>    

     <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>

     <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>

     <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>

     <td><c:out value="${row.address}"/></td>

    <td><c:out value="${row.percentage}"/></td>  

</tr> // Check this
</c:forEach> // Also this
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no collection named result(which you are trying to access in the for loop in jsp page) is defined anywhere in DbController so add following piece of code and see if it works.

```
      try  
    {  

        conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();  
        stmt = conn.createStatement();  

        res = stmt.executeQuery("select * from stud_db);  
        ArrayList Rows = new ArrayList(); //---->forgot to initialize another arraylist here. please check
  while(res.next()){  

            ArrayList row = new ArrayList();  
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){  

            row.add(res.getString(i));  

            }  

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();  
            session.setAttribute("name", res.getString(2));  
            session.setAttribute("id", res.getString(1));  
            session.setAttribute("address", res.getString(3));  
            session.setAttribute("percentage", res.getString(4));                   
            Rows.add(row);                            

            }     
            request.getSession().setAttribute("results", Rows);  
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DDLResults.jsp");  
request.getRequestDispatcher("/next.jsp").include(request,response);
 conn.close();  

    }         

    catch (SQLException se)  
    {  
        se.printStackTrace();  

    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    {  
        throw new ServletException(e.toString());  
    }  

}
```

Comment: java.lang.nullpointerexception is coming after i have made the changes

Comment: on which line are you getting this exception?

Comment: db.info.DBController.doPost(DBController.java:134)

Comment: what is written in line no 134 in that class?

Comment: Rows.add(row);  in this line

Comment: i have innitialised rows as

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Rows = null;
in servlet

Comment: please check my updated answer. i forgot to initialize the Arraylist "Rows".

Comment: again java.lang.nullpoint 


same line... it is saying that ""The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList<String>""

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") add this above that line.and let me know what happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847480/type-safety-the-expression-of-type-arraylist-needs-unchecked-conversion
check this out for the same

Answer (score 0):

when you are fetching the value from the database you need to specify the column index and not the column name.
try this

```
   Result r2= statement.executeQuery("select * from TABLE");
 while(rs2.next())

            {



int id2= rs2.getInt(1); 


String name2= rs2.getString(2);

int age2=rs2.getInt(3);

String address2= rs2.getString(4);

float percentage2 = rs2.getFloat(5);
```

i have just taken an example of the sequence of the columns. you need to take the exact column number. i hope that works. :)

Comment: please post the code where you are establishing a connection with the database, maybe that is not working. you need to specify what error you are getting.